# Trying to identify sci-fi story with problem solver using radiative cooling

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to identify a sci-fi story (either novel or part of a collection) where a traveling problem-solver character used radiative cooling with baffles to prevent airflow interfering (perhaps to condense water, or for some other part of solving a larger problem), on some human-inhabited planet. From how long it's likely been since I read it, I think it was probably written no later than the 80's, perhaps more likely 40's-60's.

It reminds me a bit of Leinster's Calhoun in his Med Service stories, but I don't think it was that, at least I haven't found it yet while rereading them. I'm not sure there was a specifically medical element to it, either.

Comment: There was a story in *Analog* in the '80s where an enterprising fellow uses a bunch of old, disused solar heat collectors in reverse as heat _radiators_ to create a local cold front and a rain shower.  If this sounds close I can try to dig up the name.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that was it, although I can't rule it out completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a Leinster story *[Sand Doom](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55818)* that involves an interstellar troubleshooter who solves a problem by setting up water condensors. I'm thinking that's it.

> By day a reflective surface was uppermost, and at sundown caterwheel trucks hooked onto it and neatly pulled it over on its back, to expose gridded black-body surfaces to the starlight.

It's one of the "Colonial Survey" stories.

Comment: And of course that issue of *Astounding* is at the Internet Archive.

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks! Just found it myself in a Leinster collection (Planets of Adventure) that includes some/most of the Colonial Survey stories as well as Forgotten Planet (which I recall reading as a kid, and having near-nightmares, because I was never fond of insects anyway).